# what does adm_updateschedule_afterbindingimport do?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am following the tutorial on BizTalk 2016 from Microsoft website [Tutorial 1: Enterprise Application Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/tutorial-1-enterprise-application-integration)

The project was compiled fine without error but I can not deploy it to BizTalk server.

The error is:

> Failed to add resource(s). Change requests failed for some resources. BizTalkAssemblyResourceManager failed to complete end type change request. Failed to update binding information. Could not find stored procedure 'adm_UpdateSchedule_AfterBindingImport'.

I have admin right on the server I would like to deploy to. However, when checking the BizTalk admin console, I saw the project but incomplete. Interestingly, I can not delete the project from BizTalk console either and the error also pointed to the procedure adm_updateschedule_afterbindingImport as the cause of failure.

[image: Screen shot of BizTalk error]

What does this procedure actually do? How do I fix the issue? BizTalk was correctly installed.

***Update:***

Tried to install Feature Pack 2, the installation was not successful and has cryptic error that I can not comprehend.

[image]

I would appreciate if someone could help me decipher it. I would like to attach the log file for your review in its entirety but the file is too big. Here is just an extract: (I can send you the entire log if necessary but I can not attach it here)

```
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Enabling baseline caching for this transaction since all active patches are MSI 3.0 style MSPs or at least one MSI 3.0 minor update patch is active
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Turning off patch optimization. {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} patch is not authored to support it.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Looking for patch transform: T10788167ToU10788167
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Validating transform 'T10788167ToU10788167' with validation bits 0x923
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Transform 'T10788167ToU10788167' is valid.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Validation 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ActionText 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Condition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdvtExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AppSearch 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Property 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Binary 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CompLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Feature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CustomAction 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Directory 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DrLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Component 3: -2147287038 

MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Icon 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LaunchCondition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Media 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ModuleDependency 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ModuleSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RegLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TextStyle 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: UIText 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: BindImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Environment 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: FeatureComponents 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LockPermissions 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ModuleComponents 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Registry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceControl 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Class 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Shortcut 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CreateFolder 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdvtUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: SensSubscription 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Extension 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ProgId 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MIME 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Verb 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: COMPlusApplication 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: COMPlusComponent 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: SelfReg 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DuplicateFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpNamespace 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpFileToNamespace 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpFilter 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpFilterToNamespace 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpPlugin 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ModuleExclusion 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AppId 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Complus 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ReserveCost 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InitializationSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: NGenExecCfg 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: IniFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: IniLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PublishComponent 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveIniFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveRegistry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceInstall 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TypeLib 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ManifestMsiResource 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: NativeImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AssemblyPrivate 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ManifestIntDependency 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ManifestExtDependency 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ManifestMSIComponents 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Validation 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ActionText 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Condition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdvtExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AppSearch 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Binary 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CompLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Feature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CustomAction 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Directory 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DrLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Component 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Icon 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LaunchCondition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ModuleDependency 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ModuleSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RegLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TextStyle 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: UIText 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: BindImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Environment 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: FeatureComponents 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LockPermissions 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ModuleComponents 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssemblyName 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Registry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceControl 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Class 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Shortcut 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CreateFolder 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdvtUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: SensSubscription 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Extension 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ProgId 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MIME 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Verb 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: COMPlusApplication 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: COMPlusComponent 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: SelfReg 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DuplicateFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpNamespace 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpFileToNamespace 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpFilter 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpFilterToNamespace 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: HelpPlugin 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ModuleExclusion 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AppId 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Complus 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ReserveCost 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InitializationSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: NGenExecCfg 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: IniFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: IniLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PublishComponent 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveIniFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveRegistry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceInstall 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TypeLib 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ManifestMsiResource 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: NativeImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AssemblyPrivate 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ManifestIntDependency 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ManifestExtDependency 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ManifestMSIComponents 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Patch 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiPatchHeaders 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Patch 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Patch 4: CREATE TABLE `Patch` ( `File_` CHAR(72) NOT NULL, `Sequence` INTEGER NOT NULL, `PatchSize` LONG NOT NULL, `Attributes` INTEGER NOT NULL, `Header` OBJECT, `StreamRef_` CHAR(72)  PRIMARY KEY `File_`, `Sequence` ) 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Patch 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified TelemetryFramework.dll.E73FACF6_453C_11DF_9078_F91756D89593 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: First patch for TelemetryFramework.dll.E73FACF6_453C_11DF_9078_F91756D89593, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: TelemetryFramework.dll.E73FACF6_453C_11DF_9078_F91756D89593 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 16384.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.TelemetryFramework.dll_GAC.E73FACF6_453C_11DF_9078_F91756D89593 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.TelemetryFramework.dll_GAC.E73FACF6_453C_11DF_9078_F91756D89593, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: MSBTS.TelemetryFramework.dll_GAC.E73FACF6_453C_11DF_9078_F91756D89593 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 16384.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified SetupHook.dll.612C4CBF_F8C9_46D1_B7B9_FA8BF9BD7226 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: First patch for SetupHook.dll.612C4CBF_F8C9_46D1_B7B9_FA8BF9BD7226, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: SetupHook.dll.612C4CBF_F8C9_46D1_B7B9_FA8BF9BD7226 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 1033, 347648.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MBSnapFmk.dll.58056EB3_3599_407B_A32B_B7DF67F5B7B6 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: First patch for MBSnapFmk.dll.58056EB3_3599_407B_A32B_B7DF67F5B7B6, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: MBSnapFmk.dll.58056EB3_3599_407B_A32B_B7DF67F5B7B6 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 590336.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MBAdminiSnapIn.dll.58056EB3_3599_407B_A32B_B7DF67F5B7B6 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: First patch for MBAdminiSnapIn.dll.58056EB3_3599_407B_A32B_B7DF67F5B7B6, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: MBAdminiSnapIn.dll.58056EB3_3599_407B_A32B_B7DF67F5B7B6 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 4857856.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.Deployment.D7298A41_5E0F_4D72_9A44_B1F4C74FF805 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.Deployment.D7298A41_5E0F_4D72_9A44_B1F4C74FF805, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: MSBTS.Deployment.D7298A41_5E0F_4D72_9A44_B1F4C74FF805 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 330240.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.Deployment_GAC.D7298A41_5E0F_4D72_9A44_B1F4C74FF805 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:801]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.Deployment_GAC.D7298A41_5E0F_4D72_9A44_B1F4C74FF805, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.Deployment_GAC.D7298A41_5E0F_4D72_9A44_B1F4C74FF805 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 330240.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.DplXlSer_GAC.D7298A41_5E0F_4D72_9A44_B1F4C74FF805 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.DplXlSer_GAC.D7298A41_5E0F_4D72_9A44_B1F4C74FF805, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.DplXlSer_GAC.D7298A41_5E0F_4D72_9A44_B1F4C74FF805 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 291328.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSXLANGsEng.dll.B5F50048_0187_4154_BDA9_C47D4997011A with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSXLANGsEng.dll.B5F50048_0187_4154_BDA9_C47D4997011A, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSXLANGsEng.dll.B5F50048_0187_4154_BDA9_C47D4997011A version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 257536.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified Comp_MSXLANGsEng.dll_GAC.B5F50048_0187_4154_BDA9_C47D4997011A with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for Comp_MSXLANGsEng.dll_GAC.B5F50048_0187_4154_BDA9_C47D4997011A, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Comp_MSXLANGsEng.dll_GAC.B5F50048_0187_4154_BDA9_C47D4997011A version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 257536.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.CommonSettings.dll.713BE73A_E3EC_4F94_8090_F2E71B6541FE with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.CommonSettings.dll.713BE73A_E3EC_4F94_8090_F2E71B6541FE, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.CommonSettings.dll.713BE73A_E3EC_4F94_8090_F2E71B6541FE version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 87040.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.CommonSettings.dll_GAC.713BE73A_E3EC_4F94_8090_F2E71B6541FE with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.CommonSettings.dll_GAC.713BE73A_E3EC_4F94_8090_F2E71B6541FE, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.CommonSettings.dll_GAC.713BE73A_E3EC_4F94_8090_F2E71B6541FE version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 87040.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.Messaging.dll.34E86A9C_7A34_4F54_8121_3268ED88DC94 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.Messaging.dll.34E86A9C_7A34_4F54_8121_3268ED88DC94, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.Messaging.dll.34E86A9C_7A34_4F54_8121_3268ED88DC94 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 76800.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.Messaging.dll_GAC.34E86A9C_7A34_4F54_8121_3268ED88DC94 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.Messaging.dll_GAC.34E86A9C_7A34_4F54_8121_3268ED88DC94, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.Messaging.dll_GAC.34E86A9C_7A34_4F54_8121_3268ED88DC94 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 76800.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll.DC6CC082_5A14_489A_B9DA_E13215E82401 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll.DC6CC082_5A14_489A_B9DA_E13215E82401, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll.DC6CC082_5A14_489A_B9DA_E13215E82401 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 1206784.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll_GAC.DC6CC082_5A14_489A_B9DA_E13215E82401 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll_GAC.DC6CC082_5A14_489A_B9DA_E13215E82401, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll_GAC.DC6CC082_5A14_489A_B9DA_E13215E82401 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 1206784.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.HttpTransport.dll.476D2E68_FF71_4D03_A078_41BD58A280D5 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.HttpTransport.dll.476D2E68_FF71_4D03_A078_41BD58A280D5, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.HttpTransport.dll.476D2E68_FF71_4D03_A078_41BD58A280D5 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 58368.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.Pipeline.dll.8C929CD9_7B00_4A41_8B57_A07265CA3FDD with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.Pipeline.dll.8C929CD9_7B00_4A41_8B57_A07265CA3FDD, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.Pipeline.dll.8C929CD9_7B00_4A41_8B57_A07265CA3FDD version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 98816.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified MSBTS.Pipeline.dll_GAC.8C929CD9_7B00_4A41_8B57_A07265CA3FDD with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for MSBTS.Pipeline.dll_GAC.8C929CD9_7B00_4A41_8B57_A07265CA3FDD, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: MSBTS.Pipeline.dll_GAC.8C929CD9_7B00_4A41_8B57_A07265CA3FDD version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 98816.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified BTSNTSvc.exe.FileId32.078A4FF3_CDCB_48F0_A16B_49026F0571B5 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for BTSNTSvc.exe.FileId32.078A4FF3_CDCB_48F0_A16B_49026F0571B5, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: BTSNTSvc.exe.FileId32.078A4FF3_CDCB_48F0_A16B_49026F0571B5 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 1033, 39424.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified BTSMIMEComps.dll.FileId32.4233735B_113A_4C12_BDB5_E7FC52898698 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for BTSMIMEComps.dll.FileId32.4233735B_113A_4C12_BDB5_E7FC52898698, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: BTSMIMEComps.dll.FileId32.4233735B_113A_4C12_BDB5_E7FC52898698 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 1033, 157696.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified Microsoft.BizTalk.DBAccessor.dll.AFCAFB6D_7531_4831_8B96_FE11E8CBDD93 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for Microsoft.BizTalk.DBAccessor.dll.AFCAFB6D_7531_4831_8B96_FE11E8CBDD93, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Microsoft.BizTalk.DBAccessor.dll.AFCAFB6D_7531_4831_8B96_FE11E8CBDD93 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 0, 12800.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified ConfigFrameworkHelper.dll.C292B659_9DE5_41D2_827B_555FE3D84FF7 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for ConfigFrameworkHelper.dll.C292B659_9DE5_41D2_827B_555FE3D84FF7, saving native info.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: ConfigFrameworkHelper.dll.C292B659_9DE5_41D2_827B_555FE3D84FF7 version for baseline at patch Native: 3.12.774.0, 1033, 734208.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: Patch {F7AA3BCD-D7EC-4604-9F47-3D5E06D29D4D} modified Configuration.exe.C292B659_9DE5_41D2_827B_555FE3D84FF7 with full-file update.
MSI (s) (58:6C) [09:24:19:817]: Baseline: First patch for Configuration.exe.C292B659_9DE5_41D2_827B_555FE3D84FF7, saving native info.
```

Comment: I would suggest you re-run the install and do a repair.   Also what Cumulative Update do you have installed?  You should be on CU3 for BizTalk 2016

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: I only have CU2... Thank you for the information... I will run CU3 hopefully it will solve the issue.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: Actually I meant I have Feature pack 2 update.. I think I have CU3. But I got error when I installed Feature Pack 2. I can not attached the whole logfile but I have it if you need to review it in its entirety

Comment: Try rebooting your server and trying FP2 again.

Comment: P.S. I would suspect that the stored procedure is for this feature from FP1 "Advanced Scheduling - Set up advanced schedules using the new capabilities with Feature Pack 1"

Comment: No luck. I have rebooted the server and I still get the same error..

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: FYI: I have even repaired BizTalk by rerunning the setup then ran FP1. FP1 failed to install successfully. So the issue is probably FP1 and not FP2

Comment: Try uninstalling FP1 then.  Patch to CU3, then install FP2.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: Will give it a swirl and let you know... many thanks!

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: I have tried to uninstall  FP2, restarted the server, update CU3 and install FP2, still have the same error...:(

Comment: Possibly the same issue on MSDN https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2e303c0a-c00a-43f4-b0b6-134892815b8a/error-installing-fp-2-for-biztalk-2016?forum=biztalkgeneral